# How do I remotely shut down a virtual machine (over SSH)?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have some KVM virtual machines running Ubuntu 11.10.
Using the GUI of the Virtual Machines I can turn them off as you would normally do it on Ubuntu.

However, I prefer to work on the VMs using SSH from the host (which also runs Ubuntu 11.10), and when trying to shutdown a VM with `shutdown 0` it simply does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shut down an Ubuntu machine from the command-line (via SSH or otherwise), run:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

- The `-P` option tells *shutdown* to power off the virtual machine at the end; contrary to its name, *shutdown* will not do this by default, instead bringing the machine into single-user/maintenance mode.
- See [`man shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) (and [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html)) for more details.